# Obtaining a token from a node app

Tags: azure-managed-identity

Interested in trying out MSI from a node app running in the app service, for authenticating with a CosmosDB.

Right now I only see a .Net sample.

Is it possible to use node right now with MSI?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, you just have to craft the token request to the local MSI endpoint.  Check out the doc topic on using MSI in App Service, and scroll to the section on "Code examples": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity#obtaining-tokens-for-azure-resources.  There's a code example for Node.js.